# Twitter Search Operators for a particular word AND others

Tags: twitter, search

I have read the Twitter search operators guidance: https://twitter.com/search-home#

but it's not clear whether you can search for a particular word plus other possible words like in the following example ...

**Particular Word**: american

and a list of other possible words

**Possible Words**: person OR citizen OR human OR alien

So in pseudo code the search would be ...

```
american AND (person OR citizen OR human OR alien)
```